# Jenkins pipeline email notifications with some part of console output in email

Tags: jenkins, groovy, email-notifications, console-output

I am running an Automated test suite on jenkins and I am able to get the status of the job using Email ext plugin. I want to include only some part of build log in email is there any way that I can do that using groovy syntax? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def notifyFailed() {
    emailext (
      subject: "FAILED : Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
      body: '''<p><font size="8" color="red">Build Failure!</font></p>
    <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${BUILD_URL}consoleText'>${JOB_NAME} [${BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>
    ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^.*?*****.*?$", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=999, maxMatches=10, showTruncatedLines=false,escapeHtml=false}''',
```